# Displaying formatted phone number from the google places api in a alert dialog on Android?

Tags: android, google-places-api

I have been using this following tutorial regarding the Google Maps API and Google Places API.

http://www.androidhive.info/2012/08/android-working-with-google-places-and-maps-tutorial/

It is very good. I have managed to display markers of nearby places on a map, and display different types of markers for different categories as well. However, I would also like to display the establishment's phone number in an alert dialog when the user clicks on one of my markers. For this, I am using a Place Detail search.

Below, I will provide a snippet of my Map Activity code that I am having problems with.

```
//Map Activity OnCreate()
//Check for null nearPlaces
if(nearPlaces.results!=null)
{
    //Loop through all places
    for(Place place:nearPlaces.results)
    {

        latitude=place.geometry.location.lat;
        longitude=place.geometry.location.lng;
        placeRef=place.reference;

        new LoadDetails().execute(placeRef);

        for(String s:place.types)
        {
            if(s.contains("restaurant"))
            {
                Drawable rMarker=this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.restaurant);

                //phone=lp.getPhone();
                iOverlay=new MyItemizedOverlay(rMarker,this);

                //GeoPoint to place on map
                gp=new GeoPoint((int)(latitude*1E6),(int)(longitude*1E6));

                //Map overlay item
                oItem=new OverlayItem(gp, place.name, place.vicinity+"\n"+"Rating: "+place.rating+" "+phone);

                iOverlay.addOVerlay(oItem);

                iOverlay.addOVerlay(oItem);
                mapOverlays.add(iOverlay);
            }
```

I have a variable String phone which I want to be the establishment's phone number.

Here is the LoadDetails class which extends AsyncTask

```
private class LoadDetails extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>
{
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
                if(placeDetails!=null)
                {
                    if(placeDetails.status.equals("OK"))
                    {
                        if(placeDetails.result!=null)
                        {
                            phone=placeDetails.result.formatted_phone_number;
                            Log.d("Phone #'s",phone);
                        }
                    }
                }



    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        String reference=params[0];
        googlePlaces=new GooglePlaces();

        try{
            placeDetails=googlePlaces.getPlaceDetails(reference);
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }


}
```

In OnPostExecute, variable phone is set and my LogCat shows the phone numbers of various places. However, when I go to my Map Activity on my phone, and click a marker of a restaurant, the variable phone is always null. How do I fix this?

Any help would be great.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: Entire MapActivity

public class Map extends MapActivity{

```
MapView mapView;
MapController mc;
GeoPoint gp, fGP;
List<Overlay> mapOverlays;
OverlayItem oItem;
MyItemizedOverlay iOverlay;

String placeRef,phone,placePhone;
double latitude,longitude;
double user_lat,user_long;
double friendLat,friendLong;
String userName,friendName,userStatus,userPhoneNumber;

//Nearest Places
PlacesList nearPlaces;

GooglePlaces googlePlaces;

PlaceDetails placeDetails;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(arg0);
    setContentView(R.layout.map);


    mapView=(MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapView);
    mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

    mc=mapView.getController();

    Intent i=getIntent();

    if (i!=null)
    {
    //Receive User's Lat and Long   
    user_lat=i.getDoubleExtra("userLAT", 0);
    user_long=i.getDoubleExtra("userLONG",0);

    userPhoneNumber=i.getStringExtra("userNUMBER");

    //Get User's Status they posted
    userStatus=i.getStringExtra("STATUS");
    //Get User's Name
    userName=i.getStringExtra("userNAME");

    //Receive Friend's Lat and Long

    friendLat=i.getDoubleExtra("friendLAT", 0);
    friendLong=i.getDoubleExtra("friendLong",0);


    //Obtain nearPlaces List from Main Activity
    nearPlaces=(PlacesList) i.getSerializableExtra("userNearPlaces");


    friendName=i.getStringExtra("friendNAME");
    Log.d("Map", userName+ " " +user_lat + " " + user_long);
    Log.d("Map2", friendName+ " " + friendLat + " " + friendLat);
    gp=new GeoPoint((int)(user_lat*1E6),(int)(user_long*1E6));

    //Friend's GeoPoint
    fGP=new GeoPoint((int)(friendLat*1E6),(int)(friendLong*1E6));

    }

    mapOverlays=mapView.getOverlays();
    Drawable marker=this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.you);


    iOverlay=new MyItemizedOverlay(marker, this);
    oItem=new OverlayItem(gp,"Your Location, "+userName,userStatus);

    iOverlay.addOVerlay(oItem);
    mapOverlays.add(iOverlay);


    Drawable fMarker=this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.smiley);

    iOverlay=new MyItemizedOverlay(fMarker,this);

    //Add friend marker to the map
    oItem=new OverlayItem(fGP,friendName+"'s Location", "This is your friend");
    iOverlay.addOVerlay(oItem);
    mapOverlays.add(iOverlay);

    //Check for null nearPlaces
    if(nearPlaces.results!=null)
    {
        //Loop through all places
        for(Place place:nearPlaces.results)
        {

            latitude=place.geometry.location.lat;
            longitude=place.geometry.location.lng;
            placeRef=place.reference;
            placePhone=place.phone;

            new LoadDetails().execute(placeRef);

            for(String s:place.types)
            {
                if(s.contains("restaurant"))
                {
                    Drawable rMarker=this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.restaurant);

                    //phone=lp.getPhone();
                    iOverlay=new MyItemizedOverlay(rMarker,this);

                    //GeoPoint to place on map
                    gp=new GeoPoint((int)(latitude*1E6),(int)(longitude*1E6));

                    //Map overlay item
                    oItem=new OverlayItem(gp, place.name, place.vicinity+"\n"+"Rating: "+place.rating+" "+placePhone);

                    iOverlay.addOVerlay(oItem);

                    iOverlay.addOVerlay(oItem);
                    mapOverlays.add(iOverlay);
                }

                if((s.contains("cafe"))||place.name.contains("cafe"))
                {
                    Drawable cafeMarker=this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.cafe);

                    iOverlay=new MyItemizedOverlay(cafeMarker,this);
                    //GeoPoint to place on map
                    gp=new GeoPoint((int)(latitude*1E6),(int)(longitude*1E6));

                    //Map overlay item
                    oItem=new OverlayItem(gp, place.name, place.vicinity+"\n"+"Rating: "+place.rating);

                    iOverlay.addOVerlay(oItem);

                    iOverlay.addOVerlay(oItem);
                    mapOverlays.add(iOverlay);

                }

                else if((s.contains("liquor_store"))||place.name.contains("liquors"))
                {
                    Drawable barMarker=this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.bar);

                    iOverlay=new MyItemizedOverlay(barMarker,this);
                    //GeoPoint to place on map
                    gp=new GeoPoint((int)(latitude*1E6),(int)(longitude*1E6));

                    //Map overlay item
                    oItem=new OverlayItem(gp, place.name, place.vicinity+"\n"+"Rating: "+place.rating);

                    iOverlay.addOVerlay(oItem);

                    iOverlay.addOVerlay(oItem);
                    mapOverlays.add(iOverlay);

                }

                else if(s.contains("department_store")||s.contains("clothing_store")||s.contains("convenience_store"))
                {
                    Drawable shopMarker=this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.mall);

                    iOverlay=new MyItemizedOverlay(shopMarker,this);
                    //GeoPoint to place on map
                    gp=new GeoPoint((int)(latitude*1E6),(int)(longitude*1E6));

                    //Map overlay item
                    oItem=new OverlayItem(gp, place.name, place.vicinity+"\n"+"Rating: "+place.rating);

                    iOverlay.addOVerlay(oItem);

                    iOverlay.addOVerlay(oItem);
                    mapOverlays.add(iOverlay);

                }

                else if(s.contains("hospital"))
                {
                    Drawable hMarker=this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.hospital);

                    iOverlay=new MyItemizedOverlay(hMarker,this);
                    //GeoPoint to place on map
                    gp=new GeoPoint((int)(latitude*1E6),(int)(longitude*1E6));

                    //Map overlay item
                    oItem=new OverlayItem(gp, place.name, place.vicinity+"\n"+"Rating: "+place.rating);

                    iOverlay.addOVerlay(oItem);

                    iOverlay.addOVerlay(oItem);
                    mapOverlays.add(iOverlay);

                }

                else if(s.contains("movie_theater"))
                {
                    Drawable movieMarker=this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.movierental);

                    iOverlay=new MyItemizedOverlay(movieMarker,this);
                    //GeoPoint to place on map
                    gp=new GeoPoint((int)(latitude*1E6),(int)(longitude*1E6));

                    //Map overlay item
                    oItem=new OverlayItem(gp, place.name, place.vicinity+"\n"+"Rating: "+place.rating);

                    iOverlay.addOVerlay(oItem);

                    iOverlay.addOVerlay(oItem);
                    mapOverlays.add(iOverlay);

                }

                else if(s.contains("pharmacy"))
                {
                    Drawable pMarker=this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.pharmacy);

                    iOverlay=new MyItemizedOverlay(pMarker,this);
                    //GeoPoint to place on map
                    gp=new GeoPoint((int)(latitude*1E6),(int)(longitude*1E6));

                    //Map overlay item
                    oItem=new OverlayItem(gp, place.name, place.vicinity+"\n"+"Rating: "+place.rating);

                    iOverlay.addOVerlay(oItem);

                    iOverlay.addOVerlay(oItem);
                    mapOverlays.add(iOverlay);

                }
                else if(s.contains("hair_care"))
                {
                    Drawable bMarker=this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.barber);

                    iOverlay=new MyItemizedOverlay(bMarker,this);
                    //GeoPoint to place on map
                    gp=new GeoPoint((int)(latitude*1E6),(int)(longitude*1E6));

                    //Map overlay item
                    oItem=new OverlayItem(gp, place.name, place.vicinity+"\n"+"Rating: "+place.rating);

                    iOverlay.addOVerlay(oItem);

                    iOverlay.addOVerlay(oItem);
                    mapOverlays.add(iOverlay);

                }

            }


        }
    }

    mapView.getController();

    mc.animateTo(gp);
    mc.setZoom(15);
    mc.setCenter(gp);

    mapView.invalidate();
}



@Override
protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}

private class LoadDetails extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>
{
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        placePhone=result;

                    //My Logcat shows phone numbers being assigned to placePhone
        Log.d("placePhone",placePhone); 

    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        String reference=params[0];
        googlePlaces=new GooglePlaces();

        try{
            placeDetails=googlePlaces.getPlaceDetails(reference);
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if(placeDetails!=null)
        {
            if(placeDetails.status.equals("OK"))
            {
                if(placeDetails.result!=null)
                {
                    phone=placeDetails.result.formatted_phone_number;

                }
            }
        }
        return phone;
    }


}

private class MyItemizedOverlay extends ItemizedOverlay<OverlayItem>
{
    private ArrayList<OverlayItem> mOverlays=new ArrayList<OverlayItem>();
    Context mContext;

    public MyItemizedOverlay(Drawable marker) {
        super(boundCenterBottom(marker));
    }

    public MyItemizedOverlay(Drawable marker,Context context) {
        super(boundCenterBottom(marker));
        mContext=context;
    }

    @Override
    protected OverlayItem createItem(int i) {
        return mOverlays.get(i);
    }

    @Override
    public int size() {
        return mOverlays.size();
    }

    public void addOVerlay(OverlayItem overlay)
    {
        mOverlays.add(overlay);
        populate();
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onTap(int i) {

        OverlayItem item= mOverlays.get(i);
        AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
        dialog.setTitle(item.getTitle());
        dialog.setMessage(item.getSnippet());


        if(item.getTitle().contains("Location"))
        {
        dialog.setNegativeButton("Send SMS", new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                Intent smsIntent=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO);
                smsIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
                smsIntent.setType("vnd.android-dir/mms-sms");
                smsIntent.setData(Uri.parse("sms:"+userPhoneNumber));
                startActivity(smsIntent);

            }
        });

        dialog.setPositiveButton("Call", new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                String uri="tel:"+userPhoneNumber.trim();
                Intent callIntent=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
                callIntent.setData(Uri.parse(uri));
                startActivity(callIntent);

            }
        });
        }
        dialog.show();

        return true;
    }


}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
oItem=new OverlayItem(gp, place.name, place.vicinity+"\n"+"Rating: "+place.rating+" "+ place.formatted_phone_number);
```

try this place.formatted_phone_number

Comment: Thanks for your response, but my Place class doesn't have a data member called phone anywhere, so I created one.

I made a String variable called placePhone = place.phone after placeRef.

After phone = placeDetails.result.formatted_phone_number; in my onPostExecute, i have the following assignment placePhone=phone;

Then in my map activity, i have
oItem=new OverlayItem(gp, place.name, place.vicinity+"\n"+"Rating: "+place.rating+" "+PlacePhone);
But still get null. I have a feeling this is a simple fix, but I can't seem to get it

Comment: could you paste your whole MapActivity?

Comment: Yes, sure, check my edit above. I'm gonna warn you that it's insanely lengthy.