# Getting Google Places result which have phone numbers

Tags: android, google-places-api

I am building an application where we can find the nearest stores which has phone number registered with google places. I am using a fairly known set of codes for this available in this address also - http://www.androidhive.info/2012/08/android-working-with-google-places-and-maps-tutorial/.

Now when I am running the downloaded code as it is (only including "rankby" instead of "radius") the code is running fine. But for filtering the result with phone number I added an 'if' in it. and then it is not returning any result at all. And I found that when I am calling the GooglePlaces.getPlaceDetails(reference) from the MainActivity it is throwing an exception. but from SinglePlaceActivity it is working fine. Can't we call Google place API twice from a single Activity?

The second problem I am also facing is if I change the MainActivity (without implementing if clause) to some other activity and call that from new MainActivity without passing anything it is giving an error subsequently the application shuts down. I think these two problems are interconnected, so I am asking together.

Thanks in advance...

required part of My MainActivity.java after alteration

```
protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
// creating Places class object
googlePlaces = new GooglePlaces();

try {
    String types = "store"; // Listing places only ambulances
    // get nearest places
    nearPlaces = googlePlaces.search(gps.getLatitude(), gps.getLongitude(), types);

} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
return null;
}


protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
// dismiss the dialog after getting all products
pDialog.dismiss();
// updating UI from Background Thread
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        /**
         * Updating parsed Places into LISTVIEW
         * */
        // Get json response status
        String status = nearPlaces.status;

        // Check for all possible status
        if(status.equals("OK")){
            // Successfully got places details
            if (nearPlaces.results != null) {
                // loop through each place
                googlePlaceDetails = new GooglePlaces();
                for (Place p : nearPlaces.results) {
                    try {
                        PlaceID = p.reference;
                        placeDetails =  googlePlaceDetails.getPlaceDetails(PlaceID);
                        txtPhone = placeDetails.result.formatted_phone_number;
                    } catch (Exception e)
                    {

                    }
                    if (txtPhone!=null){
                        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                        map.put(KEY_REFERENCE, p.reference);

                            map.put(KEY_NAME, p.name);


                        placesListItems.add(map);
                    }
                }
                ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(MainActivity.this, placesListItems,
                R.layout.list_item,
                new String[] { KEY_REFERENCE, KEY_NAME}, new int[] {
                         R.id.reference, R.id.name });

                         lv.setAdapter(adapter);
                    }
                }
                else if(status.equals("ZERO_RESULTS")){
                    // Zero results found
                    alert.showAlertDialog(MainActivity.this, "Near Places",
                            "Sorry no places found. Try to change the types of places",
                            false);
                }
                else if(status.equals("UNKNOWN_ERROR"))
                {
                    alert.showAlertDialog(MainActivity.this, "Places Error",
                            "Sorry unknown error occured.",
                            false);
                }
                else if(status.equals("OVER_QUERY_LIMIT"))
                {
                    alert.showAlertDialog(MainActivity.this, "Places Error",
                            "Sorry query limit to google places is reached",
                            false);
                }
                else if(status.equals("REQUEST_DENIED"))
                {
                    alert.showAlertDialog(MainActivity.this, "Places Error",
                            "Sorry error occured. Request is denied",
                            false);
                }
                else if(status.equals("INVALID_REQUEST"))
                {
                    alert.showAlertDialog(MainActivity.this, "Places Error",
                            "Sorry error occured. Invalid Request",
                            false);
                }
                else
                {
                    alert.showAlertDialog(MainActivity.this, "Places Error",
                            "Sorry error occured.",
                            false);
                }
            }
        });

    }

}
```

I haven't altered my GooglePlaces.java file, and as this is a very well known code I am not uploading it. if anyone can help me out it will be of immense help for me...

Again, thanks in advance.

Comment: Schakraborty i am also following the same tutorial but i got stuck in somewhere so i followed this link but it generates only nearby places you can implement the other details like phone number....http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/implementing-actionbarsherlock-search-collapsible-view-in-android/

Comment: refer this for getting phone number http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028128/displaying-formatted-phone-number-from-the-google-places-api-in-a-alert-dialog-o?rq=1

Comment: Thanks Aravinth, but I have already went through the second link you provided, but couldn't find anything that can help me. And about the first link I think you mistakenly posted some other link.

Comment: sorry man just refer this link insted of first link..http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/showing-nearby-places-using-google-places-api-and-google-map-android-api-v2/

Answer (score 0):

here has a complete code for google places API, read the comment on end of the code.

```
public class PlacesAPIActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private int PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST = 1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_places_api);

            PlacePicker.IntentBuilder builder = new PlacePicker.IntentBuilder();
            Intent intent;
            try {
                intent = builder.build(getApplicationContext());
                startActivityForResult(intent, PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST);
            } catch (GooglePlayServicesRepairableException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_place_api, menu);

    return true;
}

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

            Place place = PlacePicker.getPlace(data , this) ;

            String toastMsg = String.format("Place: %s %s", place.getName(), place.getPhoneNumber()); // HERE YOU GET THE NUMBER PHONE.
            Toast.makeText(this, toastMsg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
```

}